# How to make a sequence-polymorphic zip function that works for both finite and infinite sequences?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

I'm trying to write some sequence-related functions for my own edification and interest. So far, I have the following typeclasses:

```
class (Traversable s, Monad s) => Sequential s where
   infixr 5 ~:
   (~:) :: a -> s a -> s a
   headEx :: s a -> a
   tailEx :: s a -> s a
   null :: s a -> Bool

class (Sequential s) => Finite s where
   emptyS :: s a
```

The first of these (`Sequential`) is meant to represent all sequency things (including both finite and infinite sequences), while the second is for *only* finite sequency things.

I'm having some polymorphism-related issues in defining some typical list functions based on these. An example of these would be `zip`, which to my initial guess, would have a type signature of:

```
zip :: (Sequential s1, Sequential s2, Sequential s3) => s1 a -> s2 b -> s3 (a, b)
```

However, I run up against a problem - if I want to zip together an infinite sequence and a finite sequence, I obviously want the result to be a finite sequence as well. However, my attempt at an implementation fails, as `Sequence` has no concept of emptiness (and indeed cannot have such a concept, because infinite sequences can't be empty). Additionally, I cannot see any way of checking whether one of the `Sequential`s being passed in is actually a `Finite`, which would lead to a `Finite` result. As a result, I am not sure how I could write an implementation of this in its most general form.

I'm not sure whether my approach is at fault, or there's something in the language I am missing, but I would really like to know how I can implement a `zip` generic across finite *and* infinite sequences in any combination.

Comment: Make a `Zip` class...?

Comment: I think I see where you are going but are you sure you need all those classes? For example your `Finite s` does not guarantee *finiteness* at all - it just gives a common way to get to an *empty*  thing. For example you could make a list obviously into a instance of both and we all know lists might be infinite too (in theory) - it looks like you want to differentiate between streams and lists instead(?)

Comment: @Carsten Yeah, I do want to differentiate between streams and lists - as some list functions (like ```head```) make sense for streams, while others (like ```reverse```) do not. However, I would also like to have the ability to generically deal with all kinds of sequences - including ```Vector```s for example. The ```Seq``` is close to what I want, but it's specifically for finite things. What I'd like is ```Seq```, plus ```SeqPlus``` which also includes streams (and other infinite sequences).

Comment: As Daniel wrote: Zip-Class

Comment: You can just add `emptyS :: Maybe (s a)` to `Sequential` and consider `Nothing` as infinite and `Just (s a)` otherwise. I think that would be the simplest solution.

Comment: There is a problem with your `zip`: `zip xs (zip ys zs)` is ambiguous, because neither the first argument specifies the type of the second nor both the arguments specify the resulting type. Why not simply `zip :: Sequential s => s a -> s a -> s a`?

Comment: I think `Alternative` gets you everything you're asking from `Finite` and more. `headEx` makes no more sense in the possibly-null case than what you can get from `Foldable`, and `null` is a `Foldable` thing in general, but not so useful for infinite sequences. Frankly, I think you're probably asking too much of one type class.